# Cloudera Agent installation fails with the error "Failed to generate certificates for <host>"

Tags: certificate, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

While adding hosts, the cloudera agent installation fails with the following error

> /tmp/scm_prepare_node.EbLWUx2R
>   Failed to generate certificates for ubuntu

where ubuntu is my hostname, the ip is 127.0.1.1

The error from cloudera-scm-server.log is

```
2019-04-24 22:50:29,977 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.enterprise.JavaMelodyFacade: Entering HTTP Operation: Method:POST, Path:/add-hosts-wizard/install
2019-04-24 22:50:29,990 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfiguratorService: Creating request with id 4
2019-04-24 22:50:29,990 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.cmf.service.ServiceHandlerRegistry: Executing command GlobalHostInstall GlobalHostInstallCommandArgs{sshPort=22, userName=hadoop, password=REDACTED, passphrase=REDACTED, privateKey=REDACTED, parallelInstallCount=10, cmRepoUrl=null, gpgKeyCustomUrl=null, gpgKeyOverrideBundle=<none>, unlimitedJCE=false, javaInstallStrategy=AUTO, agentUserMode=ROOT, cdhVersion=-1, cdhRelease=NONE, cdhRepoUrl=null, buildCertCommand=/var/lib/cloudera-scm-server/certmanager/generate_host_cert, sslCertHostname=ubuntu, reqId=4, skipPackageInstall=false, skipCloudConfig=false, proxyProtocol=HTTP, proxyServer=null, proxyPort=0, proxyUserName=null, proxyPassword=REDACTED, hosts=[ubuntu], existingHosts=[]}.
2019-04-24 22:50:29,995 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.cmf.command.flow.CmdStep: Executing command work: Execute 1 steps in sequence
2019-04-24 22:50:29,996 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.cmf.command.flow.CmdStep: Executing command work: Install on 1 hosts.
2019-04-24 22:50:29,996 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.cmf.command.flow.CmdStep: Executing command work: Install on ubuntu.
2019-04-24 22:50:29,996 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfiguratorService: Adding password-based configurator for ubuntu
2019-04-24 22:50:29,998 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfiguratorService: Submitted configurator for ubuntu with id 5
2019-04-24 22:50:30,011 INFO scm-web-123:com.cloudera.enterprise.JavaMelodyFacade: Exiting HTTP Operation: Method:POST, Path:/add-hosts-wizard/install, Status:200
2019-04-24 22:50:30,017 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfiguratorProgress: ubuntu: Transitioning from INIT (PT0.021S) to CONNECT
2019-04-24 22:50:30,017 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl: Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0_14_0
2019-04-24 22:50:30,028 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl: Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
2019-04-24 22:50:30,048 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfiguratorProgress: ubuntu: Transitioning from CONNECT (PT0.031S) to AUTHENTICATE
2019-04-24 22:50:30,091 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfiguratorProgress: ubuntu: Transitioning from AUTHENTICATE (PT0.043S) to MAKE_TEMP_DIR
2019-04-24 22:50:30,505 INFO scm-web-113:com.cloudera.enterprise.JavaMelodyFacade: Entering HTTP Operation: Method:POST, Path:/express-wizard/updateHostsState
2019-04-24 22:50:30,508 INFO scm-web-113:com.cloudera.enterprise.JavaMelodyFacade: Exiting HTTP Operation: Method:POST, Path:/express-wizard/updateHostsState, Status:200
2019-04-24 22:50:31,538 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfigurator: Executing mktemp -d /tmp/scm_prepare_node.XXXXXXXX on ubuntu
2019-04-24 22:50:31,545 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfiguratorProgress: ubuntu: Transitioning from MAKE_TEMP_DIR (PT1.454S) to COPY_FILES
2019-04-24 22:50:31,760 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfigurator: Using key bundle from URL: https://archive.cloudera.com/cm6/6.2.0/allkeys.asc
2019-04-24 22:50:33,718 ERROR NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfigurator: Failed to generate certificates for ubuntu: null
2019-04-24 22:50:33,719 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfiguratorProgress: ubuntu: Setting COPY_FILES as failed and done state
2019-04-24 22:50:33,719 INFO NodeConfiguratorThread-4-0:net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl: Disconnected - BY_APPLICATION
2019-04-24 22:50:35,052 ERROR CommandPusher:com.cloudera.cmf.command.flow.WorkOutputs: CMD id: 18 Failed to complete installation on host ubuntu.
2019-04-24 22:50:35,053 ERROR CommandPusher:com.cloudera.cmf.model.DbCommand: Command 18(GlobalHostInstall) has completed. finalstate:FINISHED, success:false, msg:Failed to complete installation.
2019-04-24 22:50:35,446 ERROR ScmActive-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.components.ScmActive: ScmActive: Unable to retrieve non-local non-loopback IP address. Seeing address: ubuntu/127.0.1.1. 
2019-04-24 22:50:35,446 ERROR ScmActive-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.components.ScmActive: ScmActive failed. Bootup = false
2019-04-24 22:50:35,446 ERROR ScmActive-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.components.ScmActive: ScmActive was not able to access CM identity to validate it.
2019-04-24 22:50:35,446 ERROR ScmActive-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.components.ScmActive: ScmActive is deferring the validation to the next run in 15 seconds.
2019-04-24 22:50:35,446 INFO ScmActive-0:com.cloudera.enterprise.AbstractWrappedEntityManager: Rolling back transaction that wasn't marked for rollback-only.
java.lang.Exception: Non-thrown exception for stack trace.
    at com.cloudera.enterprise.AbstractWrappedEntityManager.close(AbstractWrappedEntityManager.java:161)
    at com.cloudera.cmf.persist.CmfEntityManager.close(CmfEntityManager.java:367)
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.components.ScmActive.markScmActive(ScmActive.java:224)
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.components.ScmActive.run(ScmActive.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please someone save me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I figured out that cert-manager utility is required to generate certificates and it is a part of cloudera-manager-agent, during the installation cloudera-manager-agent was somehow skipped, installed it and it worked like a gem.

Thanks to the following link's Auto-TLS 'Note' section: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/install_cm_server.html][1](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/install_cm_server.html)